# transparency and text problem

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm playing with the `opacity` CSS attribute.

It works nicely for the box (with at 50% or black at 30%) - the problem is that the text inside the box is *also* transparent.

I would like the text to be 100% white in a box with at 30% transparency.

The solution is to use CSS with tweaks or to use a `.png` for the background and to forget the `opacity` setting.

Tell me, how to do 30% opacity with 100% opacity text inside.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choices are:

- [Using CSS3](http://24ways.org/2009/working-with-rgba-colour): `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)`.  [***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/2sNYW/)
- Absolutely position two `<div>` tags on top of each other. One of them is the background, and has the `opacity` setting. The second one has the text in it, and a `transparent` background.
- As you hinted at in your question, you could use a `.png` file with `30%` transparency.

---

I *knew* I'd read about a way to make the `rgba` work in IE.

See: http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

```
.alpha60 {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

Comment: IE actually have its own `rgba`-like property using filter. Here´s a useful generator for that: http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: @mqchen: Thanks. That looks like a very easy way to generate the `startColorstr` and `endColorstr` for the IE filters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#box { color:white; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
```

Note: rgba does not work in IE6-8