# CSS transparancy question

Tags: css

I have got ot the following css to make my table cell's background transparent

```
background-color:black;
filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
```

the problem is, this transparency also makes the text transparent. How can i make it only target the background. or how can i over ride it when in my `<span>`. I've tired setting the occupicy to 100 in my `<span>s` for text but it doesnt override it. the text still comes out transparent

EDIT: I'm using IE6

Comment: please use search before asking question. This is a very common issue, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788564/transparency-and-text-problem/4788642#4788642

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `rgba` color which lets you set the alpha transparency of the color:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /* == black 20% opacity */
```

Read about `rgba` here: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

You can use filter for IE, code for all browsers would be:

```
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* FF3+, Saf3+, Opera 10.10+, Chrome, IE9 */ 
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#33000000',EndColorStr='#33000000'); /* IE6–IE9 */
```

Comment: its not supported by IE6 which i have to use

Comment: that works. but the transparency does not change when i change the last value of rgba(). how do you change it?