# CSS lighten child elements on parent mouseover

Tags: html, css, hover, transparency

here is my problem.
I have a `div` which contains two other `divs`: basically one for header, one for content.

I'd like to *lighten* (change alpha level, or some other method is welcomed), when the user points the mouse over the parent `div`. Colors of both child `divs` should change and become slightly lighter. I'd like to avoid javascript if possible.

How to do this in CSS?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Like this?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NHbn8/)

**Relevant CSS:**

```
#container:hover .inner {
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="inner"></div>
    <div id="right" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**Irrelevant CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow: hidden
}

.inner {
    width: 40%;
    height: 250px;
    background: #ccc
}
#left {
    float: left
}
#right {
    float: right
}
```

**Truly Irrelevant CSS:**

```
#container {
    background: #fcecfc; /* old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcecfc 0%, #fba6e1 50%, #fd89d7 51%, #ff7cd8 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fcecfc), color-stop(50%,#fba6e1), color-stop(51%,#fd89d7), color-stop(100%,#ff7cd8)); /* webkit */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcecfc', endColorstr='#ff7cd8',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
}
```

Comment: btw. how can I change the opacity only of the background color, so that it doesn't affect text color?

Comment: @ZolaKt: Use an `rgba` background: [http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NHbn8/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NHbn8/1/) - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788564/transparency-and-text-problem/4788642#4788642) for how to do it cross browser.

Comment: @ZolaKt: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/NHbn8/2/ ? Edit: You deleted that last comment, so I guess you figured it out yourself.

Comment: @OmerAhmed: Sure it will. It already works in IE9+, and can be made to work in IE7-8 with minimal effort.

Comment: so simple.. so elegant! :)

Answer (score 24):

```
  #div:hover #div1{
     color:#lightercolor;
  }
  #div:hover #div2{
     color:#lightercolor;
  }
```

Comment: This code does that. (div1 and div2 being the children, and div being parent) :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use #div:hover, perhaps?

```
#parent_div:hover #child_div_1 { background-color: #333; }
#parent_div:hover #child_div_2 { background-color: #666; }
```