# How to make one element get hovered when hover on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I need such a scenario at where if anyone hover on a div, another div will be hovered. Just like:

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="link-box">
   <a href="#">Touch the Grey Box and I get hovered!</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link-box a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

[Foddle Work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/aHe7b/1/)

If anyone hover on the `div.box`, `div.link-box` will get hovered I mean get the red color. Is it possible? Please, don't tell it like this CSS way:

```
.box:hover .link-box a {
   color: red;
}
```

My scenario is not like this. I've more complex scenario. So, it's only possible with jQuery. As I ain't good at jQuery, I can't write the script. That's why I need your help. What's the jQuery for it? May be, something like this?

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
   $('.link-box').hover();
});
```

..............................................**Update**..................................

All the answer is related with CSS. Basically, `div.link-box` is such a complex div at my webpage that if anyone hover on the `div.link-box` many action happened, like pop-up box coming, multiple child elements of `div.link-box`will change. All happened with jQuery + CSS. And I need all the hover action of `div.link-box` when anyone hover on `div.box`. I just make here `div.link-box` as a link to make you understand my problem. But, basically it's not just css change. **So, is it possible to bring all `div.link-box` hover action by hover on another div/button/link just like `div.box` by jQuery** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325519/jquery-trigger-a-hover-event-from-another-element ?

Comment: You might be able to adapt http://stackoverflow.com/a/5199243/212869 to suit your needs. Just CSS and no jQuery.

Comment: Yes, it's one kind of duplicate question #anthonymasi. I haven't got my solution/can't understand that solution. That's why, I posted similar type of question with my problem

Answer (score 3):

As long as they stay in the same layout you can use the adjacent selector (`+`) in css.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHe7b/3/)

```
.link-box a:hover, .box:hover + .link-box a{
    color: red;
}
```

The important thing to remember about the adject selector is that the two divs have to have the same parent, and the box has to immediately precede the second div.

[More information on the adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Edit:

Another option would be to wrap both divs in another div, and use the hover of the wrapper div.

This second option doesn't have the drawbacks of using the adjacent selector.  As long as the anchor is anywhere inside of the wrapper, it will be styled when any part of the wrapper is hovered.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aHe7b/6/)

Like so:

```
<div class='box-wrapper'>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="link-box"> <a href="#">Touch the Grey Box and I get hovered!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following style:

```
.box-wrapper:hover a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Upvote @smeegs, I am also curious about this problem. I tried the fiddle. Is there any way we can keep the activeness of hover to the box only. As I can check this gets activated even at the far corner of the page.?? Don't take it otherwise.

Comment: @KhushalDave, I assume you're talking about the second fiddle, I updated the link so that it's limited to the div 
http://jsfiddle.net/aHe7b/6/

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class called "hover" (to affect you `a` make it `.hover a`)

```
.hover a
{
  color: red;
}
```

Then your JQuery would read:

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
  $(".link-box").toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `:hover` css selector, I would use classes.

CSS:

```
.hover{
    color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function(){
        $('.link-box').addClass('.hover');
    },
    function(){
        $('.link-box').removeClass('hover');
    }
);
```