# How to change color of specific text in table row on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this table

```
         <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="order-delivered"><i>order</i><br/><i>delivered</i><br/>
                        <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="prep-pizza"><i>prep</i><br/><i>pizza</i><br/>
                        <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bake-pizza"><i>bake</i><br/><i>pizza</i><br/>
                        <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="out-for-deliver"><i>out for</i><br/><i>delivery</i><br/>
                        <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

What I want is that when I hover to `order-delivered` the check mark would change color. Ive tried adding a hover to the `a` but it will only activate when I only hover to it.

Is there a way to hover the `order-delivered` without changing the color of `i` but only the `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A selector targeting the `:hover` attribute of the class `order-delivered` and then the `a` child of that works.

This selector would be `.order-delivered:hover > a`.

When the `td.order-delivered` is not being hovered on, the selector `.order-delivered:hover` returns no elements. On hover, it returns the first `<td>` and then proceeds to target its only anchor child.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.order-delivered:hover a.check-mark{
    color: #FFDD00;
}
```

> **Reference:**
> [CSS lighten child elements on parent mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199154/css-lighten-child-elements-on-parent-mouseover)

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8cp5wya0/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/j0Lbrr84/) is the working example

Just add a css

```
.order-delivered:hover a{
    color: #FFDD00;
}
```