# Failing in iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

Failing to understand why the code isn't working ...

the code worked fine before i added the `for` condition.

Can anybody see where i went wrong by any chance ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for(i = 1, i < 2, i++) {
    $("#info_abonnement" + i).hover(function() {
      var pos = $(this).position();
      var width = $(this).outerWidth();
      $("#info_abonnements" + i).css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: pos.top + "px",
        left: (pos.left + width) + "px"
      }).show();
    }, function() {
      $("#info_abonnements" + i).hide()
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: foreach (i=1,i<2,i++){ is not valid sintax

Comment: Also, note, due to *closures*, the value of `i` will be the same (2) in each hover function.

Comment: Seems like you're confusing [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with [`foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Yes my bad, error while rewriting code, didn't work with for either

Comment: @Jackymamouth look at Mike_Christensen's comment, then maybe try to do it all with css like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199154/css-lighten-child-elements-on-parent-mouseover

Comment: @MikeChristensenah okey have you any suggestions ?

Comment: @depperm So you suggest that i should change z-index or something ? seems more complicated :/

Comment: @Jackymamouth if you give your child elements a similar class then you should be able to do everything with just css like my earlier comment mentions

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` is wrong it should be something like:

```
for (i=1;i<2;i++){
```

Comment: yes my bad, i had `for` in the code but changed it to foreach whilst asking my question for some reason :S

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared i. It should be:

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<2;i++)
```