# Transparent background CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with a semi-transparent background but the navigation links are also semi-transparent. How can I make it so my links do not become transparent? I have attached a copy of my code below (also available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaUbv/).

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

a{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
}

#nav{
height:30px;
background-color:#dddddd;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
opacity:0.6;
}

#right{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}

.gbt{
display:inline-block;
line-height:26px;
}

.gbtc{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.gbts{
padding:6px;
}
</style>

<div id="nav">
<ol class=gbtc>
<li class=gbt><a href=""><span class=gbts>Link</span></a></li>
<li class=gbt><a href=""><span class=gbts>Link</span></a></li>
<li class=gbt><a href=""><span class=gbts>Link</span></a></li>
<li class=gbt><a href=""><span class=gbts>Link</span></a></li>
<li class=gbt><a href=""><span class=gbts>Link</span></a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Any ideas are much appreciated and I hope you can understand what I'm trying to describe. The code I have provided is easier to see with a background image.

Thanks in advance,
Callum

Comment: See this previous answer I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788564/transparency-and-text-problem/4788642#4788642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5p3vN/

html:

```
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="nav">
    <!-- the list -->
</div>
```

css:

```
#bg{
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
}

#nav{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To set the opacity of the background only, you can set an `rgba` value for the background colour. This will not affect any child elements.

```
#nav {
  background:rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.6);
}
```

IE does not support `rgba` however. For this, you need to use a proprietary filter:

```
#nav {
  background:rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.6);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99dddddd,endColorstr=#  99dddddd);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You shouldn't need to add markup as suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The opacity in CSS is inherited to children. Full Stop. To overcome this create a the transparent background to your navigation seperately and absolutely position your li items over it with a higher z-index. There are other workarounds but they all require some form of js, but to do it with pure css this is what you want.

Comment: This answer is not correct - *you can* do it without JavaScript or separate elements; see the answer I linked to in the comment on the question.